# Write a method just once and access it in "android:onClick" everywhere in the application

Tags: android, onclick, android-xml

I have a title bar in my application. And the title bar has one button. On click of that button I display info activity. Now, as far as I know, `android:onClick` needs a reference of a public method inside the activity which has the xml set in `setContentView()`. Now, as the logic for that buttons click will be the same throughout the application, so what I want is, I will the method just once say `showInfoScreen(View view)` and put it in that buttons `onClick` attribute. And I need not write the same method everywhere. Is it possible?

Comment: Write a global method using Static keyword and access it with its class name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Write an `Activity` class, then have all of your `Activity`s extend it. For example:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void setContentView( int layoutResID ) {

        super.setContentView( layoutResID );
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnTitleBarButtonClickListener());
    }

    private void showInfoScreen() {

        // Show the info screen
    }

    private class OnTitleBarButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showInfoScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

Then all of your derived `Activity`s would extend `BaseActivity` instead of `Activity`.

The beauty of doing it this way is that any `Activity` that extends this class automatically gets this feature. No coding is required in the derived classes, just in `BaseActivity`. The only contract all of your `Activity`s will have will be to have `R.id.button` or whatever id you name it within its content.

Comment: Even easier - just have `BaseActivity` implement `View.OnClickListener`. That way you don't have to have a private inner class and you don't have to instantiate it. You simply implement the overidden `onClick(...)` method in `BaseActivity`. Also, don't find views in `onStart()` unless you really need to - do it in `onCreate(...)` instead, it's more efficient.

Comment: @MisterSquonk I didn't do that because I wanted the derived classes to be able to implement `OnClickListener` without having to call through to it's super if it were implemented already in `BaseActivity`. Gives the derived classes more of the feel that nothing is different than if it were to implement `Activity`.

Comment: @MisterSqonk what's inefficient about finding views in `onStart()`? The reason I'm not doing it on `onCreate()` is because if the super is called first in derived classes, then `setContentView()` wouldn't have been called yet and it would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write `onclick` in every Activity where you want to display infoscreen.

But `OnClick`  you just call A method `showInfoScreen(View view)` in every Activity....

And you should create class Like...`ShowInfo` and there are one static method...

```
public class ShowInfo{

 public static void showInfoScreen(View view,Context c){
  //now dispay info here 
}
}
```

Write `ShowInfo.showInfoScreen(v,YourClassName.this)` in your `onClick()` Method....

Answer (score 0):

An example of what `Vinayak.B` suggested is like this:

```
    public class yourAppUtils {

    public static void yourMethod() {
        // Do stuff
    }

}
```